# Better performance solution for Data aggregation to show based on timezone in Laravel MySQL application

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, timezone, aggregate

We are developing a website which will be having enormous user data in base tables. The timestamp is saved in UTC format in MySQL tables. The dashboard in the application will show the aggregated data in different charts, the user can also choose the "timezone".

On changing the timezone the data shall be selected/adapted accordingly. For better application performance, we want to store the aggregated data for the dashboard in some reporting tables.

Here are some examples of timezones :

Eucla, Australia is UTC +08:45, Kathmandu, Asia is UTC +05:45 , Kabul, Asia is UTC +04:30, Marquesas, Pacific is UTC -09:30.

As per our understanding, the timezone difference is a minimum of 15 minutes.

So we thought that perhaps one way is to aggregate the data in a reporting table based on a 15-minute time slot. This means the data from 8:00 to 8:15 will be calculated and stored in one table row.

The data for 8:15  to 8:30 will be stored in the next row, and so on.

Can anyone please guide us, what is the better solution for our requirement?

Comment: If the only important timezone is the one where the row originated, then add an extra column with the `DATETIME` and use that column for aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your approach is sound.  But as with all things - it depends.

In this case, it depends on specifically what you will be querying by.  If you pre-aggregate into 15 minute buckets, then there will be a natural partition at 15 minute intervals even when adjusted for time zone.  If you had chosen a 1 hour or 30 minute bucket instead, then for some time zones the data would be  in two different buckets when using what would otherwise seem like normal partitions (such as daily or hourly queries).  Using 15 minute buckets avoids that particular problem.  As you have discovered, all modern time zones are offset from UTC by some amount of hours and either 0, 30, or 45 minutes - so 15 minute buckets are ideal.

At time of query, you would convert the local time given to UTC, and query in terms of UTC.  If the user was already limited to selecting whole date values, or datetime values at 15, 30, or 60 minute intervals, then the partitions will align with your pre-aggregated data.

That said, there are alternative approaches.  Two I can think of that you should explore:

1. Does the data need to be queried by *all* time zones?  If there are only a few time zones you care about, you could keep the original UTC `timestamp` column and simply add another `datetime` column for each time zone you care about, storing the equivalent local date and time in that time zone.
2. Does the data need to be queried by time at all?  Or just by a date?  If the latter, then you could keep a UTC `timestamp` column, and keep a separate `date` column without any time component.  Date-only columns are ideal for birthdates, anniversary dates, dates of employment, and other types of "business days".